# Order of acidic strength of oxides

Tags: acid-base

> Select the correct order of acidic strength of oxides:
>
> (**A**) $\ce{SO2} > \ce{SO3} > \ce{CO2}$
>
> (**B**) $\ce{Cs2O} > \ce{K2O} > \ce{Na2O}$
>
> (**C**) $\ce{CO2} > \ce{N2O5} >\ce{B2O3}$
>
> (**D**) $\ce{SO3} > \ce{CO2} > \ce{B2O3}$

The answer given is **D**, but I think it should be **B** because I  have been taught that acidic strength increases as we go down the group. But since these are oxides, I do not know if this trend is generally true. Can you please help me what exactly is a trend to be followed in such cases?

Comment: You didn't notice that in "B" are "basic" oxides?

Comment: @Mithoron *Facepalm*, How to decide for oxides. PS , Since the community asks to show your working or else it closes the question, I wrotee what came to my mind. I noticed it but nonetheless wrote in the hope that the question won't be closed , and I would come to know how to decide strength of oxides

Comment: Well those substances are definitely not acids , they are bases.Draw the molecule of its substance and the charge of every region and you will understand which is which.

Answer (score 0):

The first group in the periodic table has metals. Metallic oxides are predominantly basic. As we go across the period the basic property decreases,  trend changing to first amphoteric then acidic elements.

The oxides mentioned above in the question do now fall into a particular group or period thus requiring brainstorming.

My suggestion is to convert the elements into their respective acids and hence comparing their acidity. Coming directly to the **D** option, $\ce{SO3}$ forming $\ce{H2SO4},$ $\ce{CO2}$ forming carbonic acid, and $\ce{B2O3}$ forming boric acid.

Now I guess it's obvious that which oxide is more acidic.

Comment: I think your answer could be significantly improved by reviewing all four choices (not focusing on the one that is marked as answer) and writing the corresponding reactions between oxides and water and supplying the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values for the products. Also, please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.